# Show a Percentage Sign in Razor

Tags: razor

I have a Share attribute, in my Model as

`public float Share { get; set; }`

It is currently pulling it through as a whole number, which is fine, is it possible to have a **%** symbol show up after it in Razor?

In my Razor I have:

`<td class="hidden-xs text-center">@t.Share</td>`

Comment: Depends how you are outputting the value in Razor. Simple solution is to write the `%` symbol in the Razor file of course.

Comment: That's not a good way to output values in Razor, take a look at `@Html.DisplayFor` for example. That way you can use the `DisplayFormat` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<td class="hidden-xs text-center">@t.Share %</td>
```

Comment: It works, just the extra percentage sign is not needed. Thanks.